# Running training using torch.distributed.launch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to run training of the following model: https://github.com/Atten4Vis/ConditionalDETR
by using a script conddetr_r50_epoch50.sh, just like it is said in README. It looks like this:

```
script_name1=`basename $0`
script_name=${script_name1:0:${#script_name1}-3}

python -m torch.distributed.launch \
    --nproc_per_node=8 \
    --use_env \
    main.py \
    --coco_path ../data/coco \
    --output_dir output/$script_name
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
NOTE: Redirects are currently not supported in Windows or MacOs.
[W C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket has failed to connect to [DESKTOP-16DB4TE]:29500 (system error: 10049 - The requested address is not valid in its context.).
[W C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:601] [c10d] The client socket has failed to connect to [DESKTOP-16DB4TE]:29500 (system error: 10049 - The requested address is not valid in its context.).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DETR\ConditionalDETR\main.py", line 258, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "C:\DETR\ConditionalDETR\main.py", line 116, in main
    utils.init_distributed_mode(args)
  File "C:\DETR\ConditionalDETR\util\misc.py", line 429, in init_distributed_mode
    torch.cuda.set_device(args.gpu)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 326, in set_device
    torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)
AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\launch.py:180: FutureWarning: The module torch.distributed.launch is deprecated
and will be removed in future. Use torchrun.
Note that --use_env is set by default in torchrun.
If your script expects `--local_rank` argument to be set, please
change it to read from `os.environ['LOCAL_RANK']` instead. See
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#launch-utility for
further instructions

  warnings.warn(
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 55928) of binary: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\launch.py", line 195, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\launch.py", line 191, in main
    launch(args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\launch.py", line 176, in launch
    run(args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\run.py", line 753, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\launcher\api.py", line 132, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conditional_detr\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\launcher\api.py", line 246, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
```

I am very new to PyTorch I do not quite understand why I'm getting this errors and what should I do to fix this?